# Pass arguments as object parameter or via object reference in Java spring

Tags: java, parameter-passing

My goal is speed and immutability of the value. Which is better if I pass the values as a method parameter or put the values in a set method and retrieve it via a get method. Let's  say I'm using a factory method. I pass my three values as parameter , now for the rest should I also pass them in the parameter or should I use getter setter methods. Let's say I have 20 users, the end result of the factory method would be selecting thousands of records. Which would be better or is there no difference?

Comment: If you're going to be selecting thousands of records, that's going to be what takes the most time, not some decision between parameters or getters. Use what looks like the best design.

Comment: If you want immutability why would there be a setter?

Comment: I think this below link might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters